# javascript regex brackets match won't work, it changes the regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, brackets

I'm trying to use this regex pattern to match this value [1]
When I use this regex:

```
new RegExp("\\["+row+"\\]/g")
```

it returns me this:

```
/\[1\]\/g/
```

instead of this:

```
/\[1\]/g
```

I have tried many things but nothing works apparently.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: pass the g flag as the 2nd argument to the ctor.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the regex delimiter when you're using the constructor:

```
new RegExp("\\["+row+"\\]", 'g')
```